# Interface Builder won't start

Tags: xcode

I have a relatively confusing problem: namely, I created several empty to basic Xcode projects and ran the iPhone and iPad emulators just to see what happens and everything is fine, empty, but fine. However, then I decided to actually add some content BUT when I double click my .xib file nothing happens :((( The Xcode loses focus, but nothing opens. The Interface Builder simply does not open :(((

Do I need to start it separately somehow or do I need to download and install it separately or something else altogether?

I did some Xcode development back in the day, 3yrs ago but since then I have seen a Mac only on TV, until a few days ago... so be nice, please :)

Thanks!

Comment: Stack and other info:

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'IBAssertionFailure', reason: 'Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iPhone Simulator. "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" (5403) failed to launch and exited with status 5. Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I am now on Xcode 5. The stack trace is as given above.

Answer (score 1):

Um... interface builder was deleted years ago. It doesn't exist anymore.

What version are you using? You should upgrade to the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: Upgraded. I was on Xcode 5. The stack trace is from Xcode 5. Did not know Interface Builder has been deleted.

Comment: Can't this post be marked as Answered by a moderator or any other admin?

Comment: @亚历山大 only the person who asked the question can mark an answer as accepted. Just hit the up vote button if my answer helped you somehow, there's no need for it to be the accepted answer.